# {{> loginButtons} not showing on device with wifi off

Tags: meteor

I am testing my app on an android device and I have a problem with the "{{> loginButtons}". The div is only showing when my device is connected via USB to the computer with its WiFi on. When i disconnect WiFi and the USB the "{{> loginButtons}" disappears.

Kindly assist. I want to have the buttons display even when my device is disconnected and WiFi switched off.

Answer (score 0):

And I want to fly =)

Think about this logically. If you are trying to authenticate a user while your device is offline, what are you doing with the authentication parameters? How --- Where --- are you going to login to?

No where. No where at all.

While your device is tethered, Meteor is smart enough to treat your computer as the application server. Without the tether, or WiFi, your phonegap bundle is trying to connect to something which doesn't exist. I suppose the package authors decided to simply hide their component if there's no application server detected, rather than code in a bunch of error messages.

Instead, what you need to do is to deploy your app. Once deployed, you can use the IP or the domain name as a parameter when you launch Meteor through Cordova. Then your buttons will render, because they can actually do something with themselves.

Comment: Much appreciated ilrein, never thought of it that way. i should concentrate on other aspects of the app and leave the "{{>logginbuttons}}" because it is working flawlessly when the device is tethered.